# UL certification and laser tag equipment

Tags: safety, laser, ul

We are a 32+-year-old laser tag equipment company. We purchase parts overseas and assemble them in the US and have hundreds of installations all over the world.

We have been told by 1 location that they are required to have all equipment UL certified.  All of our charging bricks (any cord that plugs into the wall) are UL certified but the laser tag suits and targets do not have a UL sticker on them; if the brick is UL certified is that acceptable?  All of the equipment is low voltage. The suits run off a battery that is plugged in at night to charge.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the charging bricks. If you have been making laser equipment it's likely you're familiar with these two laser product safety standards:

- FDA/CDRH 21.CFR within the U.S.
- IEC 60825-1 outside the U.S.

It's not a legal requirement that UL certifies your lasers, but they must be compliant with 21.CFR and IEC 60825-1 for the appropriate power class.

UL offers a service to certify your product for compliance with these standards. More here: https://ctech.ul.com/en/services/safety/optical-radiation-services/

It is likely that your customer has the UL requirement on the gear as a condition of their insurance, which is why they're asking you for it.

As far as the suits and targets, if they don't themselves emit laser energy, not sure where UL would come in to play. The goggles, maybe. UL could certainly tell you.